# Formatar coordenadas latitude e longitude numérica em R

Tags: r, coordenadas

Recebi um data frame com as coordenadas das escolas da cidade de São Paulo. Elas foram separadas por ponto na casa dos milhares, como um número -23.456.789. Dessa forma, o R lê o valor como **chr**.

Havia, ainda, casos em que a coordenada possuía menos caracteres e a pontuação foi colocada (talvez automaticamente) de forma errada -2.345.678.

Contudo, para o st_to_sf ler e transformar em coordenadas geoespaciais é necessário que seja numérico e que haja um ponto apenas (no meu caso, *sempre* após os dois primeiros números, p.ex. -23.456789)

Como formatar as coordenadas para decimais com ponto após os dois primeiros caracteres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que esta função resolve o problema. Na pergunta é dito que há sempre dois algarismos antes do ponto decimal, mesmo que tenha havido erros na base. Então a função

1. Remove todos os pontos;
2. Substitui os dois primeiros algarismos `\\d\\d` por o mesmo padrão `\\1` (primeiro grupo capturado pela regex) seguido de um ponto.

E finaliza transformando em `"numeric"`.

```
formatCoord <- function(x){
  y <- gsub("\\.", "", x)
  y <- sub("(\\d\\d)", "\\1.", y)
  as.numeric(y)
}

x <- c("-23.456.789", "-2.345.678", "12.345.678")

formatCoord(x)
#[1] -23.45679 -23.45678  12.34568
```

Comment: Não entendi essa sua linha `y <- gsub("\\.", "", sub("(^-*\\d+)\\.", "\\1,", x))`
testei assim `y <- gsub("\\.", "", sub("\\.", ",", x))` e deu o mesmo resultado

Comment: @AmericoNeto Veja agora, creio que está bem.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, devemos retirar os pontos nos números para ficar -23456789 em cada coluna (latitude e longitude):

```
dados$latitude <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", dados$latitude)) # O "\\." é necessário para que ele leia o . como um caracter.
dados$longitude <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", dados$longitude))
```

Depois, usaremos str_c para concatenar a separação que ele vai fazer dos números, com o str_sub, nas posições indicadas pelo start e end, colocando o ponto na posição desejada:

```
dados$latitude <- str_c(
  str_sub(dados$latitude, start = 1, end = 3),
  ".",
  str_sub(dados$latitude, start = 4)
)

dados$longitude <- str_c(
  str_sub(dados$longitude, start = 1, end = 3),
  ".",
  str_sub(dados$longitude, start = 4) # não coloquei posição final caso alguma coordenada não tenha o mesmo número de caracteres das outras
)
```

Sem isso, se usarmos o str_sub direto, ele irá substituir um dos números da coordenada pelo ".", o que causará localização errada no mapa.

Comment: Falha em `"12.345.678"`. Nada garante que coordenadas comecem sempre com um sinal negativo.

Comment: Não, esse foi o meu caso. São coordenadas das escolas da cidade de São Paulo. Ali todos são negativos. O d.f. veio com os números cheio de pontos. Se não tiver negativos, tem que mudar o _end_ para 2.

Comment: A sua solução é bem melhor. Mas eu acho que não expliquei direito. Ainda precisava corrigir que algumas coordenadas possuíam um numero a menos, então a pontuação estava errada tb. Tem como incluir esses casos nessa função?